# Redirecting user to dashboard with their user role from same login page

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, admin, dashboard

I have directed user according to the user's role in the dashboard from the same login page.

But with this the user can go to user dashboard just by simple providing the admins url.

How can I prevent a user from getting in the admin dashboard after login?

The login code is as follow.

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //if the user try to enter without typing anything.
    if($username !="" && $password !==""){
        /*$password = sha1($password);*/
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$username'AND password='$password'";

        $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Error');
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $user_id = $row['user_id'];
                $fullname = $row['fullname'];
                $username = $row['username'];
                $phone_number = $row['phone_number'];
                $state = $row['state'];
                $city = $row['city'];
                $street = $row['street'];
                $email = $row['email'];
                $user_role = $row['user_role'];


                //Starting the session for the user
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                $_SESSION['fullname'] = $fullname;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['phone_number'] = $phone_number;
                $_SESSION['state'] = $state;                
                $_SESSION['city'] = $city;
                $_SESSION['street'] = $street;
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['user_role'] = $user_role;
                if($user_role == admin){
                    header('Location:admin/admindashboard.php');
                }else{
                    header('Location:user/userdashboard.php');
                }
            }
        }else{
            $error="Username or Password is incorrect!!";
        }
    }else{
        $error = "Please Enter Username and Password";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code for `admindashboard.php`?  Where in that page do you validate the user's permissions?

Comment: is the `admin` a user input? or not and this should be `$user_role == 'admin'`

Comment: the admin is in the database table with user_role column. When the user_role is admin when login. It is redirected there. Else the user is directed to the user dashboard @dean

Comment: Here is the full code for login @David

Comment: `if($user_role == "admin"){header('Location:admin/admindashboard.php')else{header('Location:user/userdashboard.php');}` try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that certain conditions match for each user so that they do not navigate by typing into URL.

From your coding assuming that you have already redirected the users to the relevant page. Make sure you have validation checks in following files.

Add this to the header of **admindashboard.php**

```
if( $_SESSION['user_role'] != "admin")
{
    session_destroy();
    header("location: login.php");
}
```

Add this to the header of **userdashboard.php**

```
 if( $_SESSION['user_role'] != "user")
    {
        session_destroy();
        header("location: login.php");
    }
```

With the above codes, you will block other different types of users accessing different parts of the website.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I prevent a user from getting in the admin dashboard after login?

By performing the same check on that page (on `admindashboard.php`).  Whatever `$user_role` and `admin` are, you would examine the same logic on any page which requires that permission.  If the check fails, redirect (possibly to the login page, prompting the user to login with an account which can access that page).

For example:

```
if($_SESSION['user_role'] != admin) {
    header('Location:login.php');
}
```

You can't prevent a user from *requesting* any page.  You *can* respond to that request accordingly.